# How to export Unity to Android project with IL2CPP

Tags: android, macos, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

Mac OS 10.12.4
Unity 5.5.1p4

When I build an Android APK or export a Android project with IL2CPP, I will get this message:

```
Exception: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!

UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1 setupStartInfo) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:98)
.......
```

It's necessary run il2cpp.exe ?? It seem that I have to build it in Windows? How can I build in Mac?

This is "How IL2CPP works" from Unity3d.com

[image]

Comment: Did you download the NDK?

Comment: Yes, I had. android-ndk-r10e

Comment: Are you using any plugin in your project? I suggest you create an empty project and see if you can build it with  IL2CPP.

Comment: Yes, I get some plugins in my project.
It work well when I create an empty project with IL2CPP.
It has something wrong in my plugins?

Comment: I get the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Check this this issue is solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/62155613/10749547